# Laravel belongsToMany relation condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have created many-to-many relation using `belongsToMany` function:

```
class Doctor extends Model
{
...
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'doctors_to_categories', 'doctor_id', 'category_id');
    }
...
}
```

Now I want to create query with many-to-many condition. In SQL in would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `doctors`
JOIN `doctors_to_categories`
    ON `doctors_to_categories`.`doctor_id` = `doctors`.`id`
WHERE `doctors_to_categories`.`category_id` = 1
```

I have tried to achieve this like:

```
$doctors = Doctor::with(['categories' => function($query) {
    $query->where('category_id', '=', 1);
}])->get();
```

Or

```
$doctors = Doctor::with(['categories' => function($query) {
    $query->where('categories.id', '=', 1);
}])->get();
```

But it is not working. Any ideas how it should be? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `with()` function does not actually introduce a join in your query, it just loads the relation of all models as a second query. So the `with()` function couldn't possibly change the original result set.

What you are looking for is [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). This will add a `WHERE EXISTS` clause to the existing query.

```
$doctors = Doctor::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
    $query->where('categories.id', 1);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `->with()` doesn't actually limit the results of the `Doctor::...->get()` query; it simply tells Laravel what to return in the `relationships` attribute. If you actually want to enforce returning only Doctors that have a category 1 relationship, you need to use `whereHas()`:

```
$doctors = Doctor::whereHas('categories', function($query) {
  $query->where('categories.id', '=', 1); 
  // `id` or `categories.id` should work, but `categories.id` is less ambigious
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `whereHas` condition for this. Try code below:

```
$doctors = Doctor::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function($query) {
        $query->where('id', 1);
    })->get();
```